# How to transfer user accounts (user ID, password) from Magento 1.3.1 to 1.9.1?

Tags: customer-account

I've setup a brand new Magento shopping cart (1.9.1) and imported all products by hand. Now I realized that customers who created accounts on the old shopping cart are upset because they are no longer able to use their existing accounts to login into the new shopping cart...

What would be the best way to import the user accounts from the old 1.3.1 to the newest version of Magento?

Comment: you mean customer details?

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade your database? All your customers, orders, products and categories will be there automatically?

Comment: How does one upgrade the Magento database?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to export your customers separately from products.

To do this, create a dataflow profile `System -> Import/Export ->` and select 'Customers' as `Entity Type`. Export and Import as normal.

I could be wrong, but I'm fairly certain that's all you need to do. The passwords should still hash.